# how to set up parent-child relationship in Durandal?

Tags: javascript, durandal

I am trying to set up a SPA in Durandal and I need to pass JavaScript object from one view to another. I have read about parent-child relationship and I created one (or at least I think I did...) but for some reason it's not working... I spent number of hours trying to find solution but as far as I'm concerned I am doing this right. Here's the code:

1st view:

```
<h3>List of candidates:</h3>
<table border="1" class="fixed">
    <col width="150" />
    <col width="150" />
    <col width="150" />
    <col width="150" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Position Applied</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: candidates">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: address"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: positionApplied"></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.viewCandidate">View candidate</a>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCandidate">Remove candidate</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and JavaScript for it:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'canView'] , function (app, ko, cv) {


        viewCandidate: function () {

            cv.CandidateContainer(this.name, this.address, this.positionApplied);
            console.log(cv.container.name);
            document.location="#CandidateView";
        }, 

        removeCandidate: function() {
            CATObject.candidates.remove(this);
        },



    });

    return CATObject;

});
```

Now the second page when I'm trying to retrieve it:

```
<p><strong>Name: &nbsp</strong><span data-bind="text: container.name"></span></p>
<p><strong>Address: &nbsp</strong><span data-bind="text: container.address"></span></p> 
<p><strong>Position applied: &nbsp</strong><span data-bind="text:container.positionApplied"></span></p>
```

and the JavaScript for it:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout'] , function (app, ko) {


    var viewCandObject = {
        displayName: 'Candidate view',

        container: {},

        CandidateContainer: function(name, address, positionApplied) {
            viewCandObject.container.name=name;
            viewCandObject.container.address=address;
            viewCandObject.container.positionApplied=positionApplied
            console.log("CandidateContainer ran");

            viewCandObject.testContainer();

        },

    }
    return viewCandObject;

});
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm sorry, after further research I found that parent-child is not what I need. Sorry for misleading title, however I still need to resolve the problem I described.

Comment: The problem I have is that the 'container' object from the second view can be accessed and modified in the first view (running 'viewCandidate' function fires 'cv.CandidateContainer' function which contains 'testContainer' function) testContainer function prints properties of the container object in the console. But as soon as I navigate to the second view (to which the container object originally belongs) the 'testContainer' method prints only 'Undefined' values. Sorry for being not very descriptive.

Comment: Consider setting up a jsFiddle because I don't understand your problem, and if no one understands your problem it is impossible to help.

Comment: Ok this is the first view:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Nwxp/
and this is the second view:
http://jsfiddle.net/McLrt/

The problem is that running viewCandidate function in the 1st view makes functions from the 2nd view working fine (updating the container object) but when I'm going to the second view, it seems like the container has been intact and function testContainer previously printing values now prints undefined x3. I cannot explain it any clearer.